# Unauthenticated error when accessing data from external API (quandl.com) if not logged in

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code in my controller:

```
            $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/AVP.json?rows=1&api_key=dEGK9fT3NU**********",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30000,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
            ),
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            return response(['message' => 'Oops!, Something went wrong.'], 500);     
        } else {
            $result = json_decode($response);
            return (array) $result;
        }
```

and this in my web.php:

```
Route::get('/get-stocks/{symbol}', 'HomeController@getStocks');
```

the route is placed outside the middleware so I assumed that it should be able to make the request and return the correct output regardless if a user is logged in or not. Unfortunately, if no user is logged in, the request only returns

```
 { error: unauthenticated. }
```

response. Can someone please explain to me why this is happening, and what possible solution(s) I have? Thanks!

Comment: @devk the unauthenticated error only appears when no user is logged in, so I assumed it's a problem with Laravel blocking the API, which I can't understand why it would as the route is placed outside the middleware routes.

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted could really return that. Maybe show the surrounding code in routes file and the whole controller.

Comment: could you share some of the output from `php artisan route:list` so we can see/doublecheck the middleware stack?

Comment: You should double check your `HomeController` whether `middleware `exist or not because that could block unauthenticated users from accessing that controller. Let me know the result.